# How can I see what exactly contains a proprieties variable?

Tags: java, collections, key

I'm pretty new to Java, so don't kill me :)

```
 FileInputStream files = new FileInputStream(path);
Properties  prop = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(fis);
        .....
```

Let's say the files is:

```
Mary goes to school,
or,
not.
```

How can I see how the information was stocked inside the prop variable. I understand that every information, is stocked based on a key. How that key is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example of a file is not a valid properties file. The format looks something like this:

```
key1=This is my value
key2=This is another value
key3=Yet another value
```

As you can see, the answer to your question is pretty obvious given the format.

More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties).

Answer (score 0):

That's not a properties file. A properties file would have to look like this:

```
name=Mary
place.she.goes=school
```

Then, the keys would be 'name' and 'place.she.goes'; corresponding values 'Mary' and 'school'.